Sorting night shift employees tasks based on start_time
//night shift employee
id  from_time    to_time   task
1    21:00:00    22:00:00 - Cleaning(some task)
1    22:00:00    23:30:00 - Fumigation(can be some other task also)
1    4:00:00     7:00:00 - Disinfection
1    2:00:00     4:00:00 - Break
1    23:30:00    2:00:00 - Fogging

//day shift employee

2  09:00:00    10:00:00 - Cleaning(some task)
2  16:00:00    18:30:00 - Disinfection
2  11:30:00    14:00:00 - Fumigation(can be some other task also)
2  14:00:00    16:00:00 - Fogging
2  10:00:00    11:30:00 - Break

I need to sort the tasks based from_time in ascending order
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE emp_id='2' ORDER BY from_time ASC

The above query works fine for day shift employee but not sorting for night shift
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE emp_id='1'
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN CAST(from_time AS TIME) > '12:00:00' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END,
  CAST(from_time AS TIME) ASC;

The above query works fine for night shift emplyee but not sorting for day shift
How can I solve this issue?
I need one query which can sort both night shift and day shift employees tasks based on from_time.

Your database needs to store date and time (in datetime fields) for the from and to. Then you can sort by date. Relying on the time alone is never going to work because, as you've seen, you can't tell the sequence of events properly - is 02:00 earlier than 22:00, or later? There's no way to know unless you also record what day it took place on.

That's assuming these are records of the times workers came to work. Or are they daily shift pattern plans? It's a bit unclear to be honest, from your description

P.S. Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. See also [ask]

You could check the time difference between the minimum and maximum from_time per employee shift:
SELECT *
FROM testing t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, TIMEDIFF(MAX(from_time), MIN(from_time)) AS diff
    FROM testing
    GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id, IF(t2.diff > '12:00' AND from_time < '12:00', from_time + INTERVAL 24 HOUR, from_time);

Outputs:



id
from_time
to_time
task




1
21:00:00
22:00:00
Cleaning(some task)


1
22:00:00
23:30:00
Fumigation


1
23:30:00
02:00:00
Fogging


1
02:00:00
04:00:00
Break


1
04:00:00
07:00:00
Disinfection


2
09:00:00
10:00:00
Cleaning(some task)


2
10:00:00
11:30:00
Break


2
11:30:00
14:00:00
Fumigation(can be some other task also)


2
14:00:00
16:00:00
Fogging


2
16:00:00
18:30:00
Disinfection



Here's a db<>fiddle.
It would be better to link to the start of the shift in some way, but this may work depending on your shift patterns.

Add date to your FROM_TIME and correct it after midnight as next day. Your Order By could have this code:
         ADDTIME(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, 
                          INTERVAL 
                          Case When CONVERT(SubStr(FROM_TIME, 1, INSTR(FROM_TIME, ':') - 1), DECIMAL) < 12 And 
                                    SHIFT_ID = 1
                               Then 1 
                          Else 0 
                          End DAY), 
                 Cast(FROM_TIME as TIME))

This adds from_time to current date and adds 1 day for ID = 1 if from time hour is less than 12. If your night shift is from 19:00 today untill 07:00 tommorrow then put < 7 instead of < 12 in case expression's condition. Order by this is order by DATETIME.
Sample data, SQL code and result are below:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    shift_tasks (SHIFT_ID, FROM_TIME, TO_TIME, TASK) AS
        ( Select   1, '21:00:00', '22:00:00', 'Cleaning'     Union All
          Select   1, '22:00:00', '23:30:00', 'Fumigation'   Union All
          Select   1, '4:00:00',  '7:00:00',  'Disinfection' Union All
          Select   1, '2:00:00',  '4:00:00',  'Break'        Union All
          Select   1, '23:30:00', '2:00:00',  'Fogging'      Union All
          --
          Select   2, '09:00:00', '10:00:00', 'Cleaning'     Union All
          Select   2, '16:00:00', '18:30:00', 'Disinfection' Union All
          Select   2, '11:30:00', '14:00:00', 'Fumigation'   Union All
          Select   2, '14:00:00', '16:00:00', 'Fogging'      Union All
          Select   2, '10:00:00', '11:30:00', 'Break' 
        )

--    S Q L :
Select   SHIFT_ID, FROM_TIME, TO_TIME, TASK
From     shift_tasks
Order By SHIFT_ID, 
         ADDTIME(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, 
                          INTERVAL 
                          Case When CONVERT(SubStr(FROM_TIME, 1, INSTR(FROM_TIME, ':') - 1), DECIMAL) < 12 And 
                                    SHIFT_ID = 1
                               Then 1 
                          Else 0 
                          End DAY), 
                 Cast(FROM_TIME as TIME))

/*      R e s u l t :
SHIFT_ID    FROM_TIME   TO_TIME    TASK
--------    ---------   ---------  ----------------------
       1    21:00:00    22:00:00   Cleaning
       1    22:00:00    23:30:00   Fumigation
       1    23:30:00    2:00:00    Fogging
       1    2:00:00     4:00:00    Break
       1    4:00:00     7:00:00    Disinfection
       2    09:00:00    10:00:00   Cleaning
       2    10:00:00    11:30:00   Break
       2    11:30:00    14:00:00   Fumigation
       2    14:00:00    16:00:00   Fogging
       2    16:00:00    18:30:00   Disinfection          */

Without SHIFT_ID in Order By clause the result should be ...
/*      R e s u l t :
SHIFT_ID    FROM_TIME   TO_TIME    TASK
--------    ---------   ---------  ----------------------
       2    09:00:00    10:00:00   Cleaning
       2    10:00:00    11:30:00   Break
       2    11:30:00    14:00:00   Fumigation
       2    14:00:00    16:00:00   Fogging
       2    16:00:00    18:30:00   Disinfection          
       1    21:00:00    22:00:00   Cleaning
       1    22:00:00    23:30:00   Fumigation
       1    23:30:00    2:00:00    Fogging
       1    2:00:00     4:00:00    Break
       1    4:00:00     7:00:00    Disinfection            */

